# QT Serial dropping data

Tags: c++, qt

I've looked at several questions on here regarding this topic but nothing is providing me with a solution.

Testing over a VM, I have incoming data that runs either 47, 80 or 31 characters long.

Serial port's readyRead is connected to:

```
void MainWindow::readData(){
    QString buf; 
    myByteArray = serial->readAll();
    for(int i = 0; i < myByteArray.size(); ++i){
        if(myByteArray.at(i) == '\n'){
            buf.append(myByteArray.at(i));
            qDebug() << buf << endl;
            buf.clear();
        else{
            buf.append(myByteArray.at(i)); 
        }
```

I know that every message ends with a "\r\n" so we use that as a point to end the current message.

The issue I'm having is that I maybe get a clean message every 50.  It is dropping characters left and right.  I have a text file that is showing the messages being sent over serial so I can compare with what is received and it's disgusting how off they are.

I've tried readLine() as well as several other suggestions in other threads and it's always the same result.

My thought was to check to see if the messages received match the length of what I'm expecting, 47, 80, or 31 chars, and then disregard the ones that don't match. The issue with this is that I'll get an actual clean message every 2 minutes....maybe.

If I dump out what comes over the wire as soon as I get it, the results are really no different than when I'm buffering the data.

The other issue I'm having is for every message I receive, I miss about 3-4 altogether.

Any suggestions on how to handle this better?

Answer (score 1):

The `readAll` returns whatever is currently available. There is no guarantee that all data has been received.  My guess is that your data is still being transferred when you make that call.

You need to read data *until* you receive the `\r\n`.

Depending on your needs, you might find [readLine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readLine) easier to use.

Comment: One of the only things that is consistent is the reception of the \n character.  I can see that the start of the message is received, and the end, but the middle is where characters get lost.

I've tried both readAll and readLine and it's relatively the same result.

I know the full message is being sent, I'm just not receiving it via this serial port.

What is my next line of recourse?

Comment: @bauervision This is an important bit of information: it belongs in the question itself. You'd need to convince us that you indeed only receive parts of the message: e.g. use `qDebug() << line.toHex();`, where line comes from `readLine`. Perhaps you're not using flow control and you overrun a buffer somewhere. Most likely, you need to show a minimum code example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Baudrate = 38400, DataBits = 8, No Parity,One Stop, No Flow Control

These are the setting given to me from the admin, not sure if changing it on my end will matter, or if it will break the connection. Just don't know enough about this stuff yet.

Comment: thanks @KubaOber, I didn't realize that it was the slow read of readAll that was my problem, hence not stumbling on the title of the suggested post.

Using your suggested while(canReadLine) has helped for sure. I'm now getting clean messages >80% of the time, which is light years ahead of where I was. Still not 100% of the time, but this is doable for now.

As of right now, the serial port code is still in Mainwindow. Do you think moving it out of the widget would clean it up the rest of the way?

Comment: Of course. Separation of concerns and all that. Move all the communications code into a communications controller that communicates with other parts of the code via signals/slots.